# How do I sort a 2D numpy array using indicies stored in a 1D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 1D numpy array containing row index values to a 2d array.  How do I sort the 2D array based on the index values in the 1D array.  For example:

```
indicies = np.array([2,3,0,1])
matrix = np.array([[20, 200],[3,300],[100,1000],[1,1]])
```

I want to sort matrix based on the order of the index values in indicies so that I end up with a 2D array looking like:

```
[[100 1000]
 [  1    1]   
 [ 20  200]
 [  3  300]]
```

Basically the index values are associated with each row in matrix.

---

Roman's answer below seems to work on his example, but not on this one:

```
sort1 = np.array([2,4,5,7,0,1,3,6])
matrix = np.array([[20, 200],[40,400],[50,500],[70,700],[1, 1],[10,100],[30,300],[60,600]])
taken = np.take(matrix,sort1,axis=0)
print(taken)
```

I get the output:

```
[[ 50 500]
 [  1   1]
 [ 10 100]
 [ 60 600]
 [ 20 200]
 [ 40 400]
 [ 70 700]
 [ 30 300]]
```

It seems to be outputting them in the index order of the original array.  It should be ordered by the sort1 matrix indicies:

```
[[  1    1]
 [ 10  100]
 [ 20  200]
 [ 30  300]
 [ 40  400]
 [ 50  500]
 [ 60  600]
 [ 70  700]]
```

Comment: `matrices[indices,:]` does the first example

Comment: your use of index is different, `res[indices]= matrix`

Comment: hpaulj's solution seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) on specific axis:

```
np.take(matrix, indicies, axis=0)
```

---

```
[[ 100 1000]
 [   1    1]
 [  20  200]
 [   3  300]]
```

Comment: Roman, your response works great, but for some reason it doesn't work on an example I have.  See edit of my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to index with the [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) order:

```
out = matrix[np.argsort(sort1)]
```

Output:

```
array([[  1,   1],
       [ 10, 100],
       [ 20, 200],
       [ 30, 300],
       [ 40, 400],
       [ 50, 500],
       [ 60, 600],
       [ 70, 700]])
```

Or for in place modification:

```
matrix[sort1] = matrix.copy()
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get the indexes based on the sorted values.  I'm trying to put the rows of the array in the index position contained within the index array.

Comment: This is what the wide is doing, the first one requires to have all values (no missing indices), the second one (in place modification) works even with missing indices. Give it a try.

Comment: NB. The `take` approach only "worked" by mistake because `np.argsort([2,3,0,1])` is coincidentally equal to `[2,3,0,1]` ;)